# Use a mysql trigger to replace text in column

Tags: mysql, triggers

everybody!

I have a table with name order and into order have column payment_method, I need find in this columns specific text (Bank transfer) and replace with (bank) after into insert to table value Bank transfer, how I do  this via MySQL triggers?

I tried to set trigger with this value

```
delimiter |
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF order.payment_method like %Bank transfer% THEN 
    SET order.payment_method = 'Bank';
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

And trigger parametr
Time:AFTER
Event:UPDATE

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: *trigger parametr Time:AFTER Event:UPDATE* After updating the row is already updated and cannot be changed one more time. You must set the value which should be placed instead of specified value before update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_order
BEFORE INSERT
ON order
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.payment_method = CASE WHEN NEW.payment_method LIKE '%Bank transfer%'
                              THEN 'Bank'
                              ELSE NEW.payment_method
                              END;
```

And the same trigger on BEFORE UPDATE event.

Comment: Thank you of your response, but now I have this moment...  MySQL said: #1303 - Can't create a TRIGGER from within another stored routine

Comment: @otalia If you use some visual client for trigger creation then you must read carefully the User Manual to this client software.